# Break periods at the end of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017

```sql
CREATE TABLE [TABLE_1] 
(
    PLAN_NR decimal(28,6) NULL,
    START_DATE datetime NULL,
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (PLAN_NR, START_DATE) 
VALUES (1,'2020-05-01'), (2,'2020-08-01');

CREATE TABLE [TABLE_2] 
(
    PLAN_NR decimal(28,6) NULL,
    PERIOD_NR decimal(28,6) NOT NULL
);
   
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (PLAN_NR, PERIOD_NR) 
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8),
       (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8);
```

[SQL-FIDDLE-LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13b507/10)

In `TABLE_1` there are plan number and plan start date.

`TABLE_2` contains period numbers for each plan number.

I would like to compute the corresponding period start dates:

Each period is exactly 7 days long, unless the period contains a month end. Then the period should be divided into a range before the end of the month up to and including the last day of the month and a range after the end of the month.

The Select:

```
SELECT 
    t1.PLAN_NR, t2.PERIOD_NR, 
    FORMAT(DATEADD (d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ),'yyyy-MM-dd') START_DATE
FROM
    TABLE_1 t1
JOIN
    TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.PLAN_NR = t2.PLAN_NR
ORDER BY 
    t1.PLAN_NR, t2.PERIOD_NR ASC
```

This returns the start data but without the extra to consider the respective month end:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| PLAN_NR | PERIOD_NR | START_DATE |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 |         1 | 2020-05-01 |
|       1 |         2 | 2020-05-08 |
|       1 |         3 | 2020-05-15 |
|       1 |         4 | 2020-05-22 |
|       1 |         5 | 2020-05-29 |
|       1 |         6 | 2020-06-05 |
|       1 |         7 | 2020-06-12 |
|       1 |         8 | 2020-06-19 |
|       2 |         1 | 2020-08-05 |
|       2 |         2 | 2020-08-12 |
|       2 |         3 | 2020-08-19 |
|       2 |         4 | 2020-08-26 |
|       2 |         5 | 2020-09-01 |
|       2 |         6 | 2020-09-02 |
|       2 |         7 | 2020-09-09 |
|       2 |         8 | 2020-09-16 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I would like an output like this:

```
+---------+-----------+----------------------+
| PLAN_NR | PERIOD_NR |      START_DATE      |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+
|       1 |         1 | 2020-05-01           |
|       1 |         2 | 2020-05-08           |
|       1 |         3 | 2020-05-15           |
|       1 |         4 | 2020-05-22           |
|       1 |         5 | 2020-05-29           |< --- period part before new month
|       1 |         6 | 2020-06-01           |< --- period part after new month
|       1 |         7 | 2020-06-05           |
|       1 |         8 | 2020-06-12           |
|       2 |         1 | 2020-08-05           |
|       2 |         2 | 2020-08-12           |
|       2 |         3 | 2020-08-19           |
|       2 |         4 | 2020-08-26           |< --- period part before new month
|       2 |         5 | 2020-09-01           |< --- period part after new month
|       2 |         6 | 2020-09-02           |
|       2 |         7 | 2020-09-09           |
|       2 |         8 | 2020-09-16           |
+---------+-----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: you only want to tag the end/start of the period?

Comment: In your example of desired results, the row with period no. 8 and date `2020-06-19` is not present. Is that your intention? If so, what's the logic for it? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I did becaus i had a typo in the desired reuslts tabel starting with 01.08 instead opf 05.08

Comment: I want to split the 7 Day periods every time theres a End of month within the 7 Day Period

Comment: Perhaps you could try a common table expression (CTE) that calculates the start and end date for each seven day period, a second CTE that takes the rows where `Month( StartDate ) != Month( EndDate )` and splits them into two rows each (before & after month-end) and a final query that combines the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.PLAN_NR, t2.PERIOD_NR, 
    --row_number() over() but what if PERIOD_NR is not consecutive?
    t2.PERIOD_NR + SUM(num.n) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.PLAN_NR ORDER BY t2.PERIOD_NR, num.n) AS PERIOD_NR_x,
    FORMAT(CASE WHEN num.n = 1 THEN DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD (d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ))) ELSE DATEADD(d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ) END, 'yyyy-MM-dd') START_DATE
FROM
    TABLE_1 t1
JOIN
    TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.PLAN_NR = t2.PLAN_NR
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 0 AS n
    UNION ALL
    --new row for month change
    SELECT 1 AS n
    WHERE DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(d ,(t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7 , t1.START_DATE), DATEADD(d ,t2.PERIOD_NR*7 , t1.START_DATE)) = 1
) as num    
ORDER BY 
    t1.PLAN_NR, t2.PERIOD_NR ASC
```

Comment: That works. Your comment in the code made me realizeg that there might be a scenario where there are no consecutive and missing period numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions (LEAD / LAG ) to get the start and end of the period ...

```sql
    SELECT t1.PLAN_NR
    , t2.PERIOD_NR
    , FORMAT(DATEADD (d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ),'yyyy-MM-dd') START_DATE
    , CASE
       WHEN 
        lead(
          FORMAT(DATEADD (d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ),'yyyy-MM-dd')
          ) over (partition by 
                    FORMAT(DATEADD (d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ),'yyyy-MM')
                  order by t2.period_nr)
         IS NULL THEN '< --- period part before new month'
       WHEN lag(
          FORMAT(DATEADD (d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ),'yyyy-MM-dd')
          ) over (partition by 
                    FORMAT(DATEADD (d ,((t2.PERIOD_NR-1)*7) , t1.START_DATE ),'yyyy-MM')
                  order by t2.period_nr)
         IS NULL THEN '< --- period part after new month'
       END as period_break
    from TABLE_1 t1
    join TABLE_2 t2
    on t1.PLAN_NR = t2.PLAN_NR
    order by t1.PLAN_NR, t2.PERIOD_NR asc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13b507/19)

```
PLAN_NR PERIOD_NR   START_DATE  period_break
1       1           2020-05-01  < --- period part after new month
1       2           2020-05-08  (null)
1       3           2020-05-15  (null)
1       4           2020-05-22  (null)
1       5           2020-05-29  < --- period part before new month
1       6           2020-06-05  < --- period part after new month
1       7           2020-06-12  (null)
1       8           2020-06-19  < --- period part before new month
2       1           2020-08-01  < --- period part after new month
2       2           2020-08-08  (null)
2       3           2020-08-15  (null)
2       4           2020-08-22  (null)
2       5           2020-08-29  < --- period part before new month
2       6           2020-09-05  < --- period part after new month
2       7           2020-09-12  (null)
2       8           2020-09-19  < --- period part before new month
```

Comment: The  "< --- period part before new month"  and "< --- period part after new month" was meant to demonstrate the change in the desired result. Periods with a month end should not be 7 days long, but split into 2 periods. One period until the end of the month (including the last day of the month). One period with the remaining days of the interrupted period.